# software installation on RHEL4.0

Tags: linux

I have installed the package apache/httpd-2.0.65 (which is not a RPM package),but after installation when I am run the command

```
     #rpm -qi httpd
```

It is showing an output "httpd service is currently not installed in your system" and when I am run the command `service httpd status`

It is showis "httpd: unrecognized service"

I have downloaded from the below link and followed the given procedure to install:

[The corrected link](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi?Preferred=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mirrorservice.org%2Fsites%2Fftp.apache.org%2F).

<strike>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-announce/201307.mbox/%3C20130710124920.2b8793ed.wrowe%40rowe-clan.net%3E</strike>

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi?Preferred=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mirrorservice.org%2Fsites%2Fftp.apache.org%2F

Apologies.....This is the correct link

Comment: 1) Edited your post with the corrected link. 2) You installed something which is **not an RPM** and you are surprised that it does not show up on the RPM info list? 3) For maintainability you really want to make a RPM from the tarball. (How has been asked before and is on the site).  4) Did you start the HTTP deamon? Either manually or by adding it to the startup scripts and rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

You will never get results from the `rpm -qi httpd` command since you did not install it from an RPM package. Your second issue can be changed by adding a "chkconfig" line to the startup script for httpd in `/etc/init.d/`, possibly adding a "description" line as well (RHEL 4 is old enough that I don't remember if the description line is required or not), and running `chkconfig --add httpd`. See other scripts in `/etc/init.d` for the exact chkconfig line syntax you need.